# How to implement two UIButton at the same time?

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

I create 2 UIButton(different tag) and connect to 1 Action but when press at the same time, it fires 2 action with small delay.

```
- (IBAction)keysPress:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *butOne = (UIButton *)[sender viewWithTag:0];
    UIButton *butTwo = (UIButton *)[sender viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"BUT 1: %@ || BUT 2: %@",butOne, butTwo);
}
```

Log always 2times:

```
2013-02-19 09:37:40.933 TestActions[1107:c07] BUT 1: <UIButtonLabel: 0xca4d450; frame = (65 67; 9 19); text = 'â'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xca4d4c0>> || BUT 2: <UIRoundedRectButton: 0xca4d310; frame = (161 164; 139 153); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xca4d270>>

2013-02-19 09:37:40.935 TestActions[1107:c07] BUT 1: <UIRoundedRectButton: 0xca4c5c0; frame = (20 164; 135 153); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xca4c6b0>> || BUT 2: (null)
```

How to control this case? 2Buttons,1 action - fire 1time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)keysPress:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(_canClick)
    {
        _canClick = NO;
        UIButton *butOne = (UIButton *)[sender viewWithTag:0];
        UIButton *butTwo = (UIButton *)[sender viewWithTag:1];
        NSLog(@"BUT 1: %@ || BUT 2: %@",butOne, butTwo);
        [self performSelector:@selector(makeButtonCanClick) withObject:nil afterDelay:YOURTIMEINTERVAL];
    }

}

- (void)makeButtonCanClick
{
    _canClick = YES;
}
```

`_canClick` is a `BOOL` ivar , default is `YES`

Comment: Sorry, Very good solution but I can't understand soon. Very Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You do not seem to understand what the `sender` is. The sender is the button that fired the event, you would program based on what it is.

You need to save a reference to the buttons and then compare them to the sender on entry to the function.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *butOne;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *butTwo;

-(IBAction)keysPress:(UIButton *)sender {
   if(sender == [self butOne]) {
       //Do button one actions
   } 

   if(sender == [self butTwo]) {
       //Do button two actions
   }
}
```

If you don't want to keep references and use the `viewWithTag` stuff, I REALLY DO NOT SUGGEST IT, but if you do, you can:

```
- (IBAction)keysPress:(UIButton *)sender {
   UIButton *butOne = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:1];
   UIButton *butTwo = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:2];
   if(sender == butOne) {
       //Do button one actions
   } 

   if(sender == butTwo) {
       //Do button two actions
   }
}
```

Comment: Never use a tag of `0` since that is the default. Also, the tag approach is easier if you simply do `if (sender.tag == 1)`. No need to get `UIButton` for every tag.

Comment: Thanks! follow your guide, I check [sender tag] and store click buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding tags. I personally do not use them because of usability. Change the tag and you suddenly have to change everywhere you hardcoded the tag :(. I am not sure what you mean by "No need to get UIButton for every tag"?